# php mysql codeigniter character encoding

Tags: php, codeigniter, encoding, utf-8

Iam using codeIgniter and having the following settings but still my webpage is displaying "?" in case of special characters.

Database - UTF-8 encoding
Table - UTF-8
column -UTF-8
in the html file I have the following line added

```
<? header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); ?>
```

37 degrees centigrade is displayed as "maintained at 37�C"

and other special characters are also wrongly displayed.

Comment: This works in my local xampp environment. Having issue only on production

Answer (score 1):

Set this

**In `config.php`**

```
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
```

**In database connection**

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8"; 
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_unicode_ci";
```

**In Header of your file**

```
echo meta('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'equiv');
// Generates:  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: I have the same settings. Phpinfo() on my page gives "charset-utf-8" But still the characters are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'); ?>
```

to my html header worked for me!!!!

Comment: This means you are _not_ using utf8!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with **utf8_general_ci** collation.

```
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

If still your problem is not resolved, then set column collation as utf8_general_ci in your database table.

This will work.

Thanks